# How to remove an orphaned Child Domain on Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a domain (working on Server 2012 functional level) and multiple child domains.

I'm really stupid and therefore deleted the only domain controller on the child domain before demoting it and doing a clean removal. Now I need to know how to clean up the mess.

I have seen several guides such as these but none of them are for Server 2012 (and they do not work):

- http://blogs.metcorpconsulting.com/tech/?p=1333
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230306

Is there anyone who has gone through the same process? I'm basically looking for a guide or any starting point or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your self-posted answer is incorrect. That is how you remove the metadata for a failed domain controller, not an orphaned child domain. This Microsoft support article details the steps to do this correctly: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230306/en-us

Essentially, you use use `ntdsutil` with different options than the article that you linked to. This will remove the metadata for the orphaned domain. This does work on Server 2012, despite your comment in your question. If it doesn't work, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps, as per [the link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/230306) provided in [MDMarra's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/686890/218888). Unfortunately we still experienced problems with SCOM reporting that there were replication problems between the child and parent domain.
SCOM error: `The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. (0x54B)`

We were able to resolve this by opening the `AD Sites and Services`, right clicking on the parent domain and selecting `Properties`. On the `Trust` tab the child domain was still listed under outgoing and incoming trusts. Removing it here solved our issue.